# net-ldap create user with password

Tags: ruby, active-directory, netldap

I am trying to create an AD account with a password already set using the `net-ldap` gem. I am able to connect to the server fine. And I am also able to add a new user without passing the `:unicodepwd` attribute however when the new user is created there is no password set. When I do pass that attribute the user is not created and it fails with `error code 53` and the following message `Unwilling to perform`. I also get the same error if I try to replace the password of the user after I have created it. I've come across many potential answers but none of them have worked for me.

```
def initialize

        @client = Net::LDAP.new
        @client.host = server_ip
        @client.base = base
        @client.port = 389
        @client.auth(username, password)

        if @client.bind
            puts "Connected"

            add("TEST", "JEST", "testjest")
        else
            puts "Not Connected"
            display_error   
        end
    end

def add(first_name, last_name, username)
        dn = dn_value

        attrs = {
            :objectclass => ["top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "user"],
            :cn => fullname(first_name, last_name),
            :sn => last_name.capitalize,
            :givenname => first_name.capitalize,
            :displayname => fullname(first_name, last_name),
            :name => fullname(first_name, last_name),
            :samaccountname => username,
            :unicodePwd => '"password"'.encode("utf-16")
        }
        @client.add(:dn => dn, :attributes => attrs)



        if @client.get_operation_result.code != 0
            puts "Failed to add user #{fullname(first_name, last_name)}"
            display_error
        else
            puts "Added user #{fullname(first_name, last_name)}"
        end
    end
```

How would I set a password for the user when I create the user and not have to access it through the gui in order to update the password? Any help is appreciated

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I was able to get this to work once I encoded the string in a different way and connected to the SSL port 636 rather than default port 389. Using `encode` was the issue, seems like it was incorrectly encoding the password.

This is my new connection

```
@client = Net::LDAP.new
@client.host = server_ip
@client.base = base
@client.port = 636
@client.encryption(:method => :simple_tls)
@client.auth(username, password)
```

And the method which i used to encode the password

```
def encode_passwd(string)
            newstring = ""
            string = "\"" + string + "\""
            string.split("").each do |c|
                newstring = "#{newstring}#{c}\000"
            end
            return newstring
        end
```

Hope this helps someone in the future

Comment: To modify password through LDAP, it must be connected to the SSL port 636 rather than default port 389.

Answer (score 2):

The `Net::LDAP::Password.generate` does not work with ActiveDirectory. The `:unicodePwd` LDAP-Entry-Attribute (speaking ruby-gem `net-ldap` parlance), you
have to encode it like this

```
unicodepwd = "\"#{plain_text_password}\"".encode(Encoding::UTF_16LE).force_encoding(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT)
```

See details about the encoding here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223248.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I just found out there is already a password generation function included in Net::LDAP !

```
Net::LDAP::Password.generate(:md5, 'yourPlaintextPass')
```

[Documentation here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-net-ldap/Net/LDAP/Password)

Comment: in Ruby 2.1:

Net::LDAP::Password.generate(:md5, 'yourPlaintextPass')

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out ! Symbol instead of string, I edited my answer